# ngx-bootstrap tabset dragabble tabs

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I run into an issue i know it's a feature request since 2018 but it's sad that no steps made to implement such feature.
So i want to implement a dragabble tab inside of a tabset.
I cannot do it with dragula since the tab converts itself to an

`<ul>
   <li>tabs come here ar list items</li>
<ul>
<div>Tab content goes here</div>`

In this case i'd need to bind dragula to the ul itself, but i have no access to the template behind the tabset. Any ideas how can I get access to it?
I don't want to try other approaches since my tab content works perfectly fine how tabset is working, and if I change it it brakes.

[Stackblitz for the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltns4a?file=app%2Fngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this solution using ngx-boostrap

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-jztxci) [GithubRepo](https://github.com/AkhilNaidu09/drag-drop-tabs-Angular)

```
<tabset vertical="true" dndDropzone (dndDrop)="onDrop($event)" #someTabs>
    <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabsList;let index=index;">

        <ng-template tabHeading>
            <div id="tabIndex_{{index}}" (dndStart)="onDragStart($event)" [dndDraggable]="draggable.data"
                [dndEffectAllowed]="draggable.effectAllowed" [dndDisableIf]="index == 0"
                (dndCanceled)="onDraggableCancel($event);" (dndMoved)="onDraggableMoved($event,index)"
                (dndEnd)="onDragEnd($event)">

                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>{{tab.title}}
            </div>
        </ng-template>

        {{tab.content}}

    </tab>

</tabset>
```

in component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular 5";

  currentTabId: any;
  previousTabId: any;
  tabsList = [
    { title: "Dynamic Title 1", content: "Dynamic content 1", active: true },
    { title: "Dynamic Title 2", content: "Dynamic content 2" },
    { title: "Dynamic Title 3", content: "Dynamic content 3" },
    { title: "Dynamic Title 4", content: "Dynamic content 4" },
    { title: "Dynamic Title 5", content: "Dynamic content 5" }
  ];

  @ViewChild("someTabs") someTabs: TabsetComponent;

  draggable = {
    // note that data is handled with JSON.stringify/JSON.parse
    // only set simple data or POJO's as methods will be lost
    data: "myDragData",
    effectAllowed: "all",
    disable: false,
    handle: false
  };

  onDragEnd(event: DragEvent) {
    try {
      let toIndex = this.currentTabId;
      let fromIndex = this.previousTabId;
      let tabListItems = this.tabsList;
      if (toIndex === undefined || fromIndex === undefined) { // executes when user doenst to a proper drag and drop
        alert("Please drag and drop / move tabs properly");
      } else {
        if (Number(toIndex) && Number(fromIndex)) { // restricts index == 0 tab from moving
          tabListItems.splice(toIndex, 0, tabListItems.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
          this.someTabs.tabs.splice(
            toIndex,
            0,
            this.someTabs.tabs.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]
          );
          console.log(tabListItems);
        } else { // executes when from or to tab is fist tab (index == 0)
          alert("Primary tab cannot be moved or replaced with other");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) { // executes when user doenst to a proper drag and drop (any exception)
      alert("Please drag and drop / move tabs properly");
    }
  }

  onDraggableCancel(event: DragEvent) { // on drag cancel or if user doing invalid drag and drop zone we are cancelling that drag and drop task
    this.previousTabId = null; 
    this.currentTabId = null;
  }

   onDraggableMoved(event: DragEvent) {

  }

  onDragStart(event: DragEvent){
      this.previousTabId = event.target["id"].split("_")[1];

  }

  onDrop(event) {
    this.currentTabId = event.event.target["id"].split("_")[1];
    console.log("dragover");
  }

}
```